# How can I write a proper JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
const request = require('superagent');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString();

const logdir = path.join(__dirname, '../web/public/data/')
const logfile = path.join(logdir, timestamp + '.json');

// newsapi.org api key
const NEWSAPI_KEY = process.env.NEWSAPI_KEY; 

// sources endpoint
const SOURCES =  'https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en';

// articles endpoint
const ARTICLE_ENDPOINT = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?';

function getLatest(src){
    let sb = ['top','latest','popular'];
    for (let i in sb){
        let qs = querystring.stringify({source: src, sortBy: sb[i], apiKey: NEWSAPI_KEY});
        request
            .get(ARTICLE_ENDPOINT + qs)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (!err){
                    fs.appendFile(logfile, JSON.stringify(res.body.articles), (err) => {
                    });
                }
            });
    }
}

request
    .get(SOURCES)
    .end((err, res) => {
        if (!err){
            for ( var i in res.body.sources){
                getLatest(res.body.sources[i].id);
            }
        }
});
```

The file that this code writes ends up looking like this

```
[{...},{...},{...}][{...},{...},{...}]...
```

This is invalid JSON. How would I make sure that it's valid like this

```
[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]
```

I've tried so many things to make it work including applying a regex to the entire file after the fact, wrapping superagent in a function that returns a promise, and editing the file after the fact in the code that relies on this script to run. All to no avail. I know there must be a better (proper?) way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find pattern "][" and replace it with ","

Comment: This would require post processing of the file after it's written. It works, but to me seems like a very heavy way of achieving this when the solution could be more elegant and less resource intensive. I do appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Why do you need to write it out to a file first before processing? Just process it before writing it out to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than appending to the file with `fs.appendFile`, create an array before the loop, append to that and then serialise it.

```
function getLatest(src){
    let sb = ['top','latest','popular'];
    let reqs = sb.length;
    let allArticles = [];
    for (let i in sb){
        let qs = querystring.stringify({source: src, sortBy: sb[i], apiKey: NEWSAPI_KEY});
        request
            .get(ARTICLE_ENDPOINT + qs)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (!err){
                    allArticles.push(res.body.articles);
                }
                else{
                  // error happend, decrement the number of requests needed for success.
                  reqs--;
                }
                // if the number of responses is as expected, write to the json all at once.
                if(allArticles.length == reqs)
                    fs.writeFile(logfile, JSON.stringify(allArticles), (err) => {});
            });
    }
}
```

The problem was that you are serialising individual data and then appending to the file rather than joining the data, serialising in one big go and then writing to file.

Comment: My example is also not good practise.
You should use async.map or async.parallel

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried a similar solution, but the array needs live globally, because getLatest gets called multiple times for each news source. I did have an issue pushing to that object, perhaps, because I was using array.concat() - I will likely have to revisit this approach.